# Entity Framework Migration - Column not being migrated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I've added a new property in my entity and ran the command to generate a new migration, but the generated migration contains nothing. Looks like EF did not detect the column add. Is there something else I need to do in order to get the column added in the migration? This is my class:

```
 public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrganizerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public bool IsOnline { get; set; }

    public virtual User Organizer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GroupParticipation> GroupParticipations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Subject>  Subjects{ get; set; }
}
```

I have isolated the property I'm trying to add, which is "IsOnline". After adding it to the class and compiling the project, I run the following command:

```
Add-Migration AddGroupIsOnline
```

It correctly generated a new migration but here's how the migration looks like:

```
public partial class AddGroupIsOnline : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

The Up and Down does nothing. It should have added my property, is my assumption correct?

Any idea on what may be happening?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I found the "problem". Basically an automatic migration has happened in some moment after I added the IsOnline property in my Group class. Therefore when I ran `Add-Migration AddGroupIsOnline`, no changes were detected (because it was already changed by automatic migration).

I ended up finding the answer by looking at my database table and the column was already there. Then I looked at the migration table, that gets created once DB Migrations are activated, and I found the following line:

[image: Migration record]

Then I removed the IsOnline column, deleted the Automatic Migration record from the database and then re-ran:

```
Add-Migration AddGroupIsOnline
```

And here is the result:

```
public partial class AddGroupIsOnline : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Groups", "IsOnline", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("dbo.Groups", "IsOnline");
    }
}
```

So my self tip here is: if nothing is shown in the migration, there is nothing to be migrated. Verify the database and the automatic migrations in the [__MigrationHistory] table.